# Java Swingworker stops working at propertyChangeListener at 100

Tags: java, image, swingworker

I'm still building a program to test images. To update the GUI I made a swingworker and he works fine until I hit the magical number of 101 selected files.
I need to test several hundred images in one directory and don't want to sperate them to blocks of 101 images each. So has anyone an idea, why it stops working without activating the done method?
To make it more clearly:
testing Img 1, testing Img 2, ....testing Img X (x <=100), testing Img 101 stopping, no testing or done or error Img 102 (just dont progress) only message I could find out ist that the PropertyChangeEvent hits "DONE" after 101 tested images. But the property should still change and the progressBar shows 99% and the popUp shows 101/102. (Testing with numbers till 100 both work fine and show at the end 100% and 100/100 while my log gets the message "DONE"!

What I update with this worker, is a progressBar and a popUp with the current % (progressBar) and current image (e.g.101/110)
Here's the swingworker itself:

```
private void work(final File filex)
{


    worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Integer>()
    {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception                
        {
            File file = filex;

            if (file.isDirectory()) 
            {

                File[] listOfFiles = file.listFiles();
                iMax=listOfFiles.length;
                for (i= 0; i< iMax; i++) 
                {
                    aktionenTest(listOfFiles[i]);                                   //processing/working here
                    setProgress(i);
                } 
                setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));

            } 
            else 
            {
                iMax = 1;
                i = 1;
                aktionenTest(file);                                                     
                setProgress(i);
            }



            return null;


        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<Integer> chunks)
        {

        }

        @Override
        protected void done()
        {
            if(worker.isCancelled())
            {
                log.append("Cancelled!");
                setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
            }
            else
            {
                log.append("DONE");

            }
        }

    };
    worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent event) {
            System.err.println(event);
            log.append(""+event+newline);
            if(event.getPropertyName().trim().equals("progress"))
            {
                if(event.getOldValue().equals(0))
                {
                    popupCounter((Integer) event.getNewValue());
                } 
                if(iMax == 1)
                {
                    maxProg = iMax;
                    curProg = ((Integer) event.getNewValue())*100/maxProg;

                    progressBar.setValue(curProg);     
                    popupUpdate((Integer) event.getNewValue());
                }
                else
                {
                    maxProg = iMax;
                    curProg = (((Integer) event.getNewValue()+1))*100/maxProg;

                    progressBar.setValue(curProg);     
                    popupUpdate((Integer) event.getNewValue());
                }
            }


        }
    });

    worker.execute();
}
```

Here's the output of the PropertyEvent before 101

```
java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent[propertyName=progress; oldValue=99; newValue=100; propagationId=null; source=components.Bilderexplorer$4@79885c3a]
```

and after 101 (but there is still Img 102 left)

```
java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent[propertyName=state; oldValue=STARTED; newValue=DONE; propagationId=null; source=components.Bilderexplorer$4@79885c3a]
```

So has anyone an idea on what the problem is? Maybe I'm too codeblind from my own code to find it.

Greets and thanks
Zorian

Comment: Where is "DONE" in the code? Also in this for loop, you are increasing "o" instead of "i", whatever that is. `for (i= 0; i< iMax; o++)`. Where is i increased? What is `durch`?

Comment: sry I mistyped while transforming the code from the cryptic variables I use, cause they make sense in the context but no sense in a snippet and cause of english isn't my natural language( I changed it in the snippet ;) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `setProgress(i)` with i>100 it throws

```
new IllegalArgumentException("the value should be from 0 to 100");
```

You can replace it with something like `setProgress(i*100/iMax)`

The exception is never caught and just causes the thread to stop abnormally.

Comment: Yeah, I can't find an exception, but the Problem is, I can't use this operations in setProgress, cause it accepts only `int` and when I cast it, there is the rounding and then the counter doesn't fit below 100

Comment: thanks, it worked but now I have the problem, that I have to rewrite my popUp cause it shows 100/103 when 103 are finished also the progressBar has now a value of 89 while 9 files from 9 were progessed

Comment: maybe I try it with an if in the doItInBackground/or in propertyChange (but first I have to work) thanks and I give u an update tomorrow or after work^^

Comment: thanks, I changed it and did an if-clause to switch between mode <100 and >100 to get things working